# Regular expressions positioning

Tags: python, regex

I have string for example: `text_raw = 'ZB444AB'`

Is there any way with regular expressions to say that characters on positions 1,2 would be letters, characters on positions 3,4,5 would be numbers and last two characters on positions 6,7 would be again letters?

I was trying this code but it does not work:

```
text = ''.join(re.findall(r'[0-9]{3,4,5}|[A-Z]{1,2,6,7}', text_raw))
print(text)
```

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}
```

The number in the curly braces does not represent the location. It means how many times you want each character to occur.